# PHP If given date is date range

Tags: php

I'm trying to determine if the given date `$my_date`(dynamic) is `this week`,`last week`, `this month`, `last month` and `last 3 months`

```
$my_date = "29/02/2016";
$scheduled_job = strtotime($my_date);
$this_week = strtotime("first day this week");
$last_week = strtotime("last week monday");
$this_month = strtotime("first day this month");
$last_month = strtotime("first day last month");
$last_three_month = strtotime("first day -3 month");

if($scheduled_job > $this_week) {
    echo 1;
}

if($scheduled_job < $this_week and $scheduled_job >= $last_week) {
    echo 2;
}

if(strtotime($date_job) > $this_month) {
    echo 3;
}

if($scheduled_job < $this_month and $scheduled_job >= $last_month) {
    echo 4;
}

if(strtotime($date_job) > $last_three_month) {
    echo 5;
}
```

Nothing is being displayed.  How do i solve?

Comment: You have mistake in $my_date, correct format is `$my_date = "29-02-2016";`

Comment: You can use `elseif` if your date ranges don't overlap.

Answer (score 2):

I modified your code, if needed further modify your IF statements, but date creation works as expected, you get DateTime objects and you can do whatever you like from them:

```
$my_date = "29/02/2016";

//this week,last week, this month, last month and last 3 months
$scheduled_job =  DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $my_date);

//test your date
//echo $scheduled_job->format('Y-m-d');

$this_week = new DateTime(date('Y-m-d',strtotime("first day this week")));
$last_week = new DateTime(date('Y-m-d',strtotime("last week monday")));
$this_month = new DateTime(date('Y-m-d',strtotime("first day this month")));
$last_month = new DateTime(date('Y-m-d',strtotime("first day last month")));
$last_three_month = new DateTime(date('Y-m-d',strtotime("first day -3 month")));


if($scheduled_job > $this_week) {
    echo 1;
}

if($scheduled_job < $this_week and $scheduled_job >= $last_week) {
    echo 2;
}

if($scheduled_job > $this_month) {
    echo 3;
}

if($scheduled_job < $this_month and $scheduled_job >= $last_month) {
    echo 4;
}

if($scheduled_job > $last_three_month) {
    echo 5;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`$dateJob` is never defined (third and fifth if statement).

Maybe did you meant `$scheduled_job`?

Moreover, try to format `$my_date` in a different manner because if you use `/` as separator, this means `m/d/y`

```
$my_date = "29-02-2016";
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply do `str_replace` of `'/'` slash:

```
$my_date = str_replace('/', '.', '29/02/2016');
```

Because `strtotime`documentation says:

> Dates in the m/d/y or d-m-y formats are disambiguated by looking at
>   the separator between the various components: if the separator is a
>   slash (/), then the American m/d/y is assumed; whereas if the
>   separator is a dash (-) or a dot (.), then the European d-m-y format
>   is assumed.

Answer (score 1):

I pref using the DateTime class.

```
$date = new \DateTime();

$thisMonday = $date->modify('first day of this week'); // to get the current week's first date
$lastMonday = $date->modify('last monday'); // to get last monday
$firstDayThisMonth = $date->modify('first day of this month'); // to get first day of this month
$firstDayLastMonth = $date->modify('first day of this month'); // to get first day of last month
$firstDayThreeMonthAgo = new \DateTime($firstDayThisMonth->format('Y-m-d') . ' - 3 months'); // first day 3 months ago

$my_date = str_replace('/', '.', "29/02/2016");
$scheduled_job = new \DateTime($my_date);

// Now you can do the checks.
```